# How do you do develop an SBT project, itself?

Tags: sbt, scala-ide, sbt-aspectj

Background: I've got a Play 2.0 project, and I am trying to add something to do aspectj weaving using aspects in a jar on some of my classes (Java). (sbt-aspectj doesn't seem to do it, or I can't see how).  So I need to add a custom task, and have it depend on compile. I've sort of figured out the dependency part.  However, because I don't know exactly what I'm doing, yet, I want to develop this using the IDE (I'm using Scala-IDE).  Since sbt projects (and therefore Play projects) are recursively defined, I assumed I could:

1. Add the eclipse plugin to the myplay/project/project/plugins.sbt
2. Add the sbt main jar (and aspectj jar) to myplay/project/project/build.sbt:

   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.scala-sbt" % "main" % "0.12.2",
     "aspectj" % "aspectj-tools" % "1.0.6"
   )
3. Drop into the myplay/project
4. Run sbt, run the eclipse task, then import the project into eclipse as a separate project.

I can do this, though the build.scala (and other scala files) aren't initially considered source, and I have to fiddle with the build path a bit.  However, even though I've got the sbt main defined for the project, both eclipse IDE and the compile task give errors:

```
> compile
[error] .../myplay/project/Build.scala:2: not found: object keys
[error] import keys.Keys._
[error]        ^
[error] .../myplay/project/SbtAspectJ.scala:2: object Configurations is not a member of package sbt
[error] import sbt.Configurations.Compile
[error]            ^
[error] .../myplay/project/SbtAspectJ.scala:3: object Keys is not a member of package sbt
[error] import sbt.Keys._
[error]            ^
[error] three errors found
```

The eclipse project shows neither main nor aspectj-tools in its referenced-libraries.  However, if I give it a bogus version (e.g. 0.12.4), reload fails, so it appears to be using
the dependency.

So,...
First: Is this the proper way to do this?
Second: If so, why aren't the libs getting added.
(Third: please don't let this be something dumb that I missed.)

Comment: Really, ANY pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

If you are getting the `object Keys is not a member of package sbt` error, then you should check that you are running sbt from the base directory, and not the /project directory.

Answer (score 1):

### sbt-aspectj

> sbt-aspectj doesn't seem to do it, or I can't see how.

I think this is the real issue. There's a plugin already that does the work, so try making it work instead of fiddling with the build. Using plugins from build.scala is a bit tricky.
Luckily there are sample projects on [github](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj/blob/008e17fded741eff69e838e5b626ffac29412310/src/sbt-test/compile/aspects/project/SampleBuild.scala):

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj.{ Aspectj, aspectjSettings, compiledClasses }
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj.AspectjKeys.{ binaries, compileOnly, inputs, lintProperties }


object SampleBuild extends Build {
  ....

  // precompiled aspects
  lazy val tracer = Project(
    "tracer",
    file("tracer"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ aspectjSettings ++ Seq(
      // stop after compiling the aspects (no weaving)
      compileOnly in Aspectj := true,

      // ignore warnings (we don't have the sample classes)
      lintProperties in Aspectj += "invalidAbsoluteTypeName = ignore",

      // replace regular products with compiled aspects
      products in Compile <<= products in Aspectj
    )
  )
}
```

### How do you do develop an SBT project, itself?

If you're interested in hacking on the build still the first place to go is the [Getting Started](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/index.html) guide. Specifically, your question should be answered in [.scala Build Definition page](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html).

I think you want your build to utilize `"aspectj" % "aspectj-tools" % "1.0.6"`. If so it should be included in `myplay/project/plugins.sbt`, and your code should go into `myplay/project/common.scala` or something. If you want to use IDE, you have have better luck with building it as a sbt plugin. That way your code would go into `src/main/scala`. Check out sbt/sbt-aspectj or sbt/sbt-assembly on example of sbt plugin structure.